# Convert string to bool or Get,Set or Dictionary?

Tags: c#

Building a quest-based game, I have a class for each quest `(Quest1423, Quest1424, Quest1425)`, and several static/reference classes `(QuestStart, QuestEnd)`.

I want to have the static/reference class `QuestEnd` update the CURRENT quest class `boolean QuestComplete` without me coding the name of which quest (because they change).

I'm trying to create a variable in each quest class `public static string Name = "Quest1425";` to reference `bools` in the quest class (`public static bool QuestCompleted;` from the static/reference class `Quest1425.QuestCompleted = true; to generic "Name".QuestComplete = true;`

Is there a generic way I could turn the string Name into the variable name in the static/reference classes? Instead of typing each quest `name.QuestCompleted`, is there a way I could use the variable `string.QuestCompleted`?

(I know my capitalization format is off, this is just an example)

(Please do not reference me to `MSDN`, I don't understand anything from that site)

(Dictionary appears to just move a string from one spot to another, could you explain Dictionary(string,Variable)? Bc I want it generic not specific identifier.)

(Could I use Get/Set somehow to populate the quest class `bool` from the static/reference class void/function?)

Comment: I'm afraid that based on list of your requirements to the answer it is unlikely small concrete post on SO would answer this question.... (Hopefully I'm wrong and someone can explain possible approaches in a way you can understand)

Comment: That means you have a `class` called `Quest` and instances of the class called `Quest1423`, `Quest1424`, and `Quest1425`. And in the `Quest` class, you have a flag called `QuestComplete`? I am a bit confused with the question... or the `Quest142x` are all different Quest classes but having the same flag `QuestCompleted`

Comment: Unfortunately if you don't understand MSDN, it will be quite hard to program. And it sounds like Dictionary is exactly what you want, or just a variable containing the current quest.

Comment: I believe he is using a class per quest approach.  Ideally this is a bad practice considering a class per file and with 142x quests, that is a lot of classes, and a lot of files; redundancy.

Comment: Additionally, (I haven't posted a question in ages) your question title doesn't exactly constrain to the problem or question you are asking.  I suggest editing the title a bit to better represent the underlying issue being expressed here.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your approach to quest implementation is not ideal for this situation?  Instead of having a class per quest, why not implmemt a generic Quest class, and create an instance of the class for each quest?  Store these instances in a Dictionary instance, and reference the Quest by name.  You can even delegate the functionality of each Quest by passing in a delegate when you create them:

```
public class Quest {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }

   private delegate mOnQuestDoThis, mOnQuestDoThat;
   public static Dictionary<string, Quest> All { get; set; }
   public static Quest CurrentQuest { get; set; }

   public Quest(string name, delegate onQuestDoThis, delegate onQuestDoThat) {
       Name = name;
       IsCompleted = false;
       mOnQuestDoThis = onQuestDoThis;
       mOnQuestDoThat = onQuestDoThat;
       All.Add(name, this);
       if(CurrentQuest == null) {
          CurrentQuest = this;
       } 
   }

   static Quest() { All = new Dictionary<string, Quest>(); }

   public DoThis(...) { mOnQuestDoThis(...); }
   public DoThat(...) { mOnQuestDoThat(...); }
}
```

Then in your further implementation to create a new Quest:

```
new Quest("Quest1432", new delegate () => { ... }, new delegate () =>  { ... });
```

Then, to complete a quest, set the current quest, or complete the current quest:

```
Quest.All["Quest1432"].IsCompleted = true;
Quest.CurrentQuest = new Quest(...);
Quest.CurrentQuest.IsCompleted = true;
```

The `All` dictionary should be inside each `Player` instance as a member instead of being statically generated so that each player has their own quests (this depends on the game idea obviously).  Further, you can store a quest by name, by ID, or by what ever you want to use to identify them.

This way you can have more flexibility when you want to add more quest to your game.  You won't need to modify existing code, or bloat your code with thousands of classes that all represent the same data structure.